# Why am I getting nullpointer Exception in this Program?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am new to Java , can anyone explain why i am getting a **Null pointer Exception** ?
Additionally can anyone explain other **reliable** input methods besides Scanner.

The Error

> Exception in thread **"main"** java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> > at Theater.main(**Theater.java:18**)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Theater 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        int Screen;
        Screens[] X = new Screens[5];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(" '0' to exit");
            System.out.println(" '1-5' for Booking Seats");
            System.out.println(" '10' for Displaying Seating Status");
            System.out.println("Enter Screen Number : ");
            Screen = input.nextInt();
            if(Screen >= 1 && Screen <= 4)
                X[Screen-1].bookSeat();
            else if(Screen == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Thank You for Booking Seats in PVR Cinemas.");
                System.in.read();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }while(true);

    }
}
class Screens
{
    private
        int[] Gold = new int[3];
        int[] Platinum = new int[3];
        int[] Diamond = new int[3];
        int g,d,p;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX=3;
    public  Screens()
    {
        for( int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            Gold[i] = 0;
            Platinum[i] = 0;
            Diamond[i] = 0;
            g = d = p = 0;
        }
    }
    public void bookSeat()
    {
        int n=0,choice,i;
        System.out.println("\t\tMenu");
        System.out.println("1.Gold \tAvailable Seats : "+(3-g));
        System.out.println("2.Platinum \tAvailable Seats : "+(3-p));
        System.out.println("3.Diamond \tAvailable Seats : "+(3-d));
        System.out.println("4.Return to Main Menu");
        System.out.println("Your Choice : ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice>=1 && choice<=3)
        {
                    System.out.print("How many Seats ? : ");
                    n = input.nextInt();
                    if( n<=0 )
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please Check your Input.");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if( n>=MAX )
                    {
                        System.out.println("The Maximum Number of Seats is : "+MAX);
                    }
        }
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                if(g+n >3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Housefull!");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    int total = 0;
                    System.out.print("Seat Numbers are : ");
                    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                        Gold[g++] = 1;
                        System.out.print("\t"+g);
                    }
                    total = 100 * n;
                    System.out.println("Total Money to be paid : "+total);
                }
            break;
            case 2:
                if(p+n >3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Housefull!");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    int total = 0;
                    System.out.print("Seat Numbers are : ");
                    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                        Platinum[p++] = 1;
                        System.out.print("\t"+p);
                    }
                    total = 125 * n;
                    System.out.println("Total Money to be paid : "+total);
                }
            break;
            case 3:
                if(d+n >3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Housefull!");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    int total = 0;
                    System.out.print("Seat Numbers are : ");
                    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                        Diamond[d++] = 1;
                        System.out.print("\t"+d);
                    }
                    total = 150 * n;
                    System.out.println("Total Money to be paid : "+total);
                }
            break;
            case 4:
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Sorry, That's an invalid Choice!");

        }
        return;
    }
    public void viewSeats()
    {
        int i;
        System.out.println("Gold Category : ");
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        System.out.print("\t "+Gold[i]);
        System.out.println("Platinum Category : ");
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        System.out.print("\t "+Platinum[i]);
        System.out.println("Diamond Category : ");
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        System.out.print("\t "+Diamond[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **populate** your `Scrrens array`. In other words you have only initialized your Scrren array but never initialized its elements.If you don't initialize its elements they get default values which in this case is **null**. Guess what happens when you invoke somemethod on null. Boom **NPE** you get.

```
Screens[] X = new Screens[5];
x[0] = new Screen();
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you initialize the array `X` you do not initailize its members so when doing `X[Screen-1]` you are using a null object (even if the index is in the bounderies).

Answer (score 2):

Because your array `X` doesn't have any elements in it, so by default every element is initialized to `null`. So basically you are trying to do this `null.bookseat()` which results in a `NullPointerException`.

It is also important to note that if `Screen` is ever `5` (which is allowed by your condition `<= 5`) then you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your array only have indices `0,1,2,3,4` (5 total)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

You get a NullPointerException because you have declared an array to hold 5 screen objects but you have never initialized the 5 slots with an actual Screen object

Thus when you try to use the

```
X[Screen-1].bookSeat();
```

you are referencing a null element in the array and of course you cannot call a method of a null object

You could add a check before using the object and initialize the screen

```
if(Screen >= 1 && Screen <= 4) {
    if (X[Screen-1] == null) 
       X[Screen-1] = new Screens();

    X[Screen-1].bookSeat();
}
```

also there is something weird in your usage. Arrays start at zero index but you use the zero as a value to exit from the program, so the element at index zero is never used.

Comment: Sorry, but How to initialize? an example might help.

Answer (score 2):

Your array `X` is being created, but the elements are not initialized, they are still null. I think you are expecting to have your array initialized like this:

```
Screens[] X = new Screens[5];
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    X[x] = new Screens();
}
```

Comment: i can't understand, for example in C++, if i have a class called Screen and i have a statement like Screen X[5]; it means that X is an object-array of Screen class having a size of 5, then what is this X[x] ?? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Because after `Screens[] X = new Screens[5];` all 5 elements of array X are null!!

Answer (score 1):

One more way to populate your Screens array

```
Screens[] X = { new Screens(), new Screens(), new Screens(),new Screens(), new Screens() };
```

you may find using [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) from Collections more useful.